# Optimise code - All() .Contains

Tags: c#, linq, contains

```
var result = this.context.Pro.Where(p => p.Supplier.Active).Select(p => p.id).ToList();

return proIds.All(result.Contains);
```

This does work, just wondering if there is a better way. `proIds` need to be contained within Pro.

Comment: How does that even build?  Contains is a method

Comment: @Sam implicit method group conversion.  It'll build fine.

Comment: proid is a list of products. result is also a list of products. I need to make sure all proids are in the results list (all have active suppliers)

Comment: @CharlesMager  Whoda thunk it.  Thanks, I'll be looking that up.

Comment: @Sam, I found it on StackOverflow and thought "I'll be having that"

Comment: @Byyo sorry, forgot the press the accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a more efficient version using [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) that uses a set:

```
var activeIDs = this.context.Pro.Where(p => p.Supplier.Active).Select(p => p.id);
return !proIds.Except(activeIDs).Any();
```

Another approach is using a `HashSet` + `All`:

```
var activeIDSet = new HashSet<int>(context.Pro.Where(p => p.Supplier.Active).Select(p => p.id));
return proIds.All(activeIDSet.Contains);
```

Comment: Actually I think you might have that the wrong way around. Shouldn't it be `return !proIds.Except(activeIDs).Any(); ` ?

Answer (score 5):

`List.Contains` is an O(n) operation, so it's better to create a `HashSet`, whose `Contains` operation is O(1). I assume your Ids are suitable to be stored in a hash set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashSet<int>` to store your ids (making the assumption your ids are of type `int`) and it's constructor `public HashSet(IEnumerable<T> collection)` like this: `var result = new HashSet<int>(this.context.Pro.Where(p => p.Supplier.Active).Select(p => p.id));` Now when you have `HashSet<int>` the search operation (the `Contains` method in your `proIds.All(result.Contains);` call) is with constant algorithm complexity O(1);